# Calling locally hosted server from Expo App

Tags: react-native, axios, expo

I am creating a react-native app and one of the components I have created contains a property which is populated through data coming from an http request.

Right now I am hosting the server from my laptop, however I am testing the app on my phone using the Expo app. Since these are two separate devices, the http://localhost:3000 calls are not working and thus I can not tell whether or not my component is properly working.

Is there any way for me to run the server on my laptop and set it up so that the http requests from within the Expo app reach the server?

Comment: did you get this working?

Answer (score 46):

You can get the IP address at runtime using the Expo manifest:

```
import Constants from "expo-constants";
const { manifest } = Constants;

const api = (typeof manifest.packagerOpts === `object`) && manifest.packagerOpts.dev
  ? manifest.debuggerHost.split(`:`).shift().concat(`:3000`)
  : `api.example.com`;
```

This will set `api` constant to the address of your local development machine in development mode and to whatever address you use in production. Note that apps deployed through App Store / Play Store seems to have packagerOpts `undefined`. That's why we have additional `typeof` condition. In that case we assume it's production build.

More about the manifest here: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/how-expo-works/#expo-development-server

Comment: Note that this will only work if you serve your app over LAN. Here is a feature request to enable this for tunnels as well: https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/tunnels-to-additional-ports

Comment: this Work for me, It is important to mention that it is necessary to add `http://` before the IP

Comment: `Constants` has been moved to `react-native-unimodules` in recent versions.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @borislemke. I did a quick research and according to https://docs.expo.io/versions/v36.0.0/sdk/constants/ `expo-constants` is still the module that exposes `Constants.manifest`. Are you saying it won't work this way? I don't use Expo anymore so it's difficult for me to actually test it.

Answer (score 33):

```
import Constants from "expo-constants";

const { manifest } = Constants;

const uri = `http://${manifest.debuggerHost.split(':').shift()}:4000`;
```

Comment: saved me precious time of my life

Comment: use @Emi solution below for those of you coming after `debuggerHost` got deprecated

Answer (score 14):

The solution using **debuggerHost** stopped working for me after setting EAS Update, so I started doing that instead:

```js
const uri = Constants?.expoConfig?.hostUri
  ? Constants.expoConfig.hostUri.split(`:`).shift().concat(`:8080`)
  : `yourapi.com`;
```

In case you are using TS, for some reason **hostUri** is not typed but the prop exists.

Comment: This is the most up to date answer, the ones using `manifest` are deprecated now

Answer (score 13):

You should replace the `http://localhost:3000/` address with the ip address of your computer.

On windows, open a prompt and type `ipconfig`, check the line of your network interface and get the address IPV4, should look like `192.168.1.20`. Then you can make your calls with fetch and an url looking like `htt://192.168.1.20/routname`.

By the way, your computer (server) and your device must be on the same local network. Wifi and lan shares the same network.

Comment: Lifesaver.!!!!!!!!.
Also, use the port number like this. http://192.168.1.20:3000/routname

Answer (score 6):

To add to [Tadeusz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49198103/4134960), in the current version of Expo (I'm on 32.0.0 right now), you would import `Constants` rather than `Expo` (even though the constants are referenced in the docs as `Expo.Constants.manifest`), so it would look like

```js
import { Constants } from 'expo';
const { manifest } = Constants;
```

Also, prepending the generated address with the protocol seems to be a must to make it all work.

Answer (score 5):

For the life of me, I could not get any solution that I found (including all the ones on this page) to work. I spent a couple days trying. Finally, I just gave up and worked around this whole problem by using `localtunnel` and exposing my service running on `localhost:8080` to the web. Worked first try when calling it from my expo app. Maybe not the greatest long-term solution, but not so bad, either. I hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 4):

Tad Lispy's solution worked for me.  But I formatted it a little bit differently.

I also added support for react-native-web, using the `document` object.

```js
import Constants from "expo-constants";

//const inProduction = manifest.packagerOpts == null;
const inProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';
const inExpo = Constants.manifest && Constants.manifest.debuggerHost;
const inBrowser = typeof document !== 'undefined';

export const apiDomain =
    inProduction ? 'mywebsite.com'
  : inExpo ? Constants.manifest.debuggerHost!.split(`:`).shift()
  : inBrowser ? document.location.hostname
  : 'unknown';

console.log('apiDomain:', apiDomain);

const protocol = inProduction ? 'https' : 'http';

const apiUrl = `${protocol}://${apiDomain}/...`;
```

Answer (score 2):

**Works with React-Native app on iOS physical device that's running separately from your computer, but is calling a localhost API:**

Your API call before may have looked like this: `http://localhost:3000/api/user/login`

On windows, open up your command prompt (press the windows key on your keyboard, type `cmd`, press enter; this should open it), then enter `ipconfig` into your command prompt and press enter.

This should give you a big list of data. Scroll down until you you see this field: `IPv4 Address.....`. Take it's value from the right side (something like this: `192.168.1.33`).

Next, plug this number into your API call like so: `http://192.168.1.33:3000/api/user/login`

Make sure you and your device are both using the same wifi network. This should now work.

**Summary:**

Old API call: `http://localhost:3000/api/user/login`

New API call: `http://192.168.1.33:3000/api/user/login`

Comment: Hi, in production, what IP address should i use?

Comment: @kd12345 The real address that you're hosting on. For example: https://myrealdomain.com/api/user/login

Comment: Hi and thank you for getting back to me. My problem is i want to show an HTML file. I have done this you requested but now the url doesnt open in my react native webview but opens in my browser

Answer (score 1):

One another easy way.  First you need to on Mobile HotSpot and connect to laptop using Mobile HotSpot. Then check you ip assign to your computer and replace api url http://localhost:80/ address to http://192.168.5.43:80/ in react-native source where you use.

Replace port 80 to your api server port no.

Make sure you have open server port (80) in firewall in laptop.

Test api in android rest-client https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sn.restandroid [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sn.restandroid) (url :  http://192.168.5.43:80/api)

Answer (score 1):

I tried some of it and it didn't work, finally simply used ngrok

Answer (score 1):

Quick and easy solution that works straight forward!

[Localtunnel docs](https://theboroer.github.io/localtunnel-www/)

1. Install Localtunnel globally (requires NodeJS) to make it accessible anywhere:

`npm install -g localtunnel`

2. Start a webserver on some local port (eg http://localhost:8000) and use the command line interface to request a tunnel to your local server:

`lt --port 8000`

3. You will receive a url, for example https://gqgh.localtunnel.me, that you can share with anyone for as long as your local instance of lt remains active. Any requests will be routed to your local service at the specified port.

Answer (score 0):

[In addition to the above] If using Laravel artisan serve, pass in your computer ip as host parameter:

```
php artisan serve --host 192.168.0.19 --port 8000
```

Answer (score 0):

How to call a locally hosted server from Expo is explained in details from Divyanshu Singh with some solutions:

- By using ngrok or localtunnel
- By running the server on 0.0.0.0 (*this
  solution worked for me*)

https://dsinecos.github.io/blog/How-to-call-a-locally-hosted-server-from-expo-app

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't know why but this particular **IP address** is somehow related to the Android Emulator. I tried the above solutions (Machine's private IPv4) but that also didn't work. So, if someone's developing inside an Android emulator then you can use this **IP address**.

```
http://10.0.2.2
```

And don't forget to add the **PORT** number of your ***localhost*** server.

Answer (score 0):

In my project I normally get the local dev server via config so I adapted @tiagob's answer to just patch the `localhost` address:

```
let uri = Config.host;
if (uri.includes('localhost') && manifest.debuggerHost)
  uri = uri.replace(
    'localhost',
    manifest.debuggerHost.split(':').shift()
  );
```

In production the config won't include `localhost` so this code will just return the unmodified configuration variable.

Answer (score 0):

With Laravel, the [pera](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67510857/13278252) response may help...

Start your server with this commands:
`php artisan serve --host 192.168.0.19 --port 8000`

replace '192.168.0.19' with your ip address