# I am using axios library for fetching local json file in react native but when I make get request it gives me Unhandled promise rejection

Tags: react-native, axios

I am making a sign in form and want to fetch the data(user's credential basically) from the local json file I created db1.json. The url which I am getting after starting json server and copying and pasting that link in my browser, is redirecting to my json data but when I am trying to fetch the data using axios I am getting [Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Network Error] again and again

```
    import React from 'react';
    import {View, Button} from 'react-native';
    import axios from 'axios;

    const SignUpScreen = ({navigation}) => {

    const getDataFromJson = async()=>{
    try {
        console.log("Entered here")
        const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/usersType');
        console.log('Response from Json : ',response);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error we get :",error)
    }
} 
    return <View>
        <Button title = "Click me here" 
             onPress = {()=> getDataFromJson()}
        />


</View>

    }
```

my json file contain

```
    {
"usersType" : [
    {"superAdmin" : [{"username" : "superadminuser", "password" : "superadminpassword"}]},
    {"admin" : [{"username" : "adminuser", "password" : "adminpassword"}]},
    {"clubAdmin" : [{"username" : "clubAdminuser", "password" : "clubAdminpassword"}]},
    {"user" : [{"username" : "user", "password" : "password"}]}
     ]
    }
```

This the result I am getting when a button is being pressed on

[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Network Error]
- node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:16:24 in createError
- node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\xhr.js:81:25 in handleError
- ... 9 more stack frames from framework internals

Answer (score 0):

This is because react-native 0.59 and higher doesn't allow `http` connections on Android. It is suggested to use https-enabled APIs in production but for debugging, you can add `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` property to the `application` tag in your AndroidManifest.xml and this will solve the issue.

Like this:

```
<manifest xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
.... 
<application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" tools:targetApi="28">
... 
</application>
</manifest>
```

**EDIT**

I just saw you're using localhost in your url. This is wrong because `localhost` refers to your current device (in this case, your phone). And since the server is running on the PC, axios wouldn't be able to find it. Try replacing `localhost` with your PC's IP address. Your PC's IP can be found by running the command `ipconfig` in your terminal. The IP will be listed under the IPv4 section.

Example: `http://192.168.xx.x:3000/usersType`

Comment: but in react-native there is no file AndroidManifest.xml is present. Can you please tell where to use the above mentioned code or any code we have to import to work in our code to make it work on our local device. After testing in multiple devices not just in android emulator, same problem persist

Comment: @SaquibAsghar are you using expo or react-native?

Comment: If you're using vanilla react native, the file will be under yourAppDir/android/app/src/main

Comment: @fsosciety I am creating an application in react native with the help of expo

Comment: @SaquibAsghar Updated my answer. Try the solution and see if it works.

Comment: sorry to bug you again and again but after changing localhost name with my ip address still its not working on my physical device as well as in android emulator too and plus when I am using 192.168.xx.x:3000/usersType this url over to my browser address bar it showing "connection cannot be establish" message. @fsociety

Comment: @SaquibAsghar What's your IP address? You do know xx.x must be replaced with the last two sections of your ip address, right?

Comment: Yeah I do know that in place of xx.x I have to use my ip address and I mentioned my IP address 192.168.1.109:3000/usersTypes but still axios is unable to hit the URL and plus when I am using this IP address (192.168.1.109:3000/usersTypes) on to my browser still no connection is being establish and I have given connection permission for private as well as public in my firewall setting, still no change

Comment: @SaquibAsghar I can't think of another reason why it isn't working. Make sure to check your ip address again (its reassigned when you reboot your router or reconnect with wifi) and then use this format to connect http:// 192.168.xx.x/usersType. Don't forget the http:// before ip.

Comment: it's frustrating, if am using examples of Axios(their http's URL having some content) from the web into my code then it is able to fetch the data but, with localhost it is failing

Comment: Here's a similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47962529/combine-nodejs-react-native-axios-cors

Comment: is there any role of the tunnel. Do I need to figure that?

Comment: I don't think its the tunnel. Tunnel issues don't cause network errors.