# Customizing code at build-time in React Native with Create React Native App and Expo

Tags: react-native, expo, create-react-native-app

Generally, is there a way to customize the app code during build step?

Specifically, there is the typical need to make requests from the application to the local backend ([[1]](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/issues/154), [[2]](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10404), [[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42189301/axios-in-react-native-not-calling-server-in-localhost), [[4]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47417766/calling-locally-hosted-server-from-expo-app)).

- `localhost` doesn't work since the server and the app are on different hosts (when using Android emulator or an actual physical device).
- The actual IP address of the host in the same network works but in a multi-developer project it's a hassle for everyone to constantly change the constant IP in the code to that of their development machine.

With Webpack a case like that could be solved with [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) replacing a placeholder with the IP address of the machine the build is happening on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ended up using somewhat hacky approach inspired by transformers like [`react-native-typescript-transformer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-typescript-transformer) or [`react-native-sass-transformer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sass-transformer). It's idea is pretty much equivalent to the mentioned [`DefinePlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) of Webpack.

First, some transformer files in the project directory (you can name them however you like, just update the references):

**configBuildReplacements.js**

```
// whatever logic you need

module.exports = {
    API_HOST_PLACEHOLDER: `http://${getLocalNetworkAddress()}:3000`,
    SOME_OTHER_DYNAMIC_VALUE: someFun(),
}
```

**configBuildReplaceTransformer.js**

```
const semver = require('semver')    

let upstreamTransformer = null

const reactNativeVersionString = require('react-native/package.json').version
const reactNativeMinorVersion = semver(reactNativeVersionString).minor

if (reactNativeMinorVersion >= 56) {
    upstreamTransformer = require('metro/src/reactNativeTransformer')
}
else if (reactNativeMinorVersion >= 52) {
    upstreamTransformer = require('metro/src/transformer')
}
else if (reactNativeMinorVersion >= 47) {
    upstreamTransformer = require('metro-bundler/src/transformer')
}
else if (reactNativeMinorVersion === 46) {
    upstreamTransformer = require('metro-bundler/build/transformer')
}
else {
    // handle RN <= 0.45
    const oldUpstreamTransformer = require('react-native/packager/transformer')
    upstreamTransformer = {
        transform({ src, filename, options }) {
            return oldUpstreamTransformer.transform(src, filename, options)
        },
    }
}


module.exports.transform = function (src, filename, options) {
    // handle RN >= 0.46
    if (typeof src === 'object') {
        ({ src, filename, options } = src)
    }

    const replacements = require('./configBuildReplacements')

    const modifiedSrc = Object.keys(replacements).reduce(
        (src, replacementKey) => src.replace(
            new RegExp(replacementKey, 'g'),
            replacements[replacementKey],
        ),
        src,
    )

    return upstreamTransformer.transform({
        src: modifiedSrc,
        filename,
        options,
    })
}
```

The exported `transform` function uses the exported object from the previous file `configBuildReplacements.js` as a dictionary to replace key substrings with value substrings in the source code before handing this code to the default (upstream) transformer.

And to connect this new transformer to the project:

- with Expo, add the `transformer` packager option to `app.json`:

  ```
  {
    "expo": {
      "packagerOpts": {
        "transformer": "configBuildReplaceTransformer.js"
      }
    }
  }
  ```
- without Expo, add `getTransformModulePath()` to `rn-cli.config.js` (which is the default path to the optional config file for React Native CLI, which is extremely poorly documented at the moment of this writing):

  ```
  module.exports = {
      getTransformModulePath() {
          return require.resolve('./configBuildReplaceTransformer')
      },        
  }
  ```

After this is done, just like with `DefinePlugin`, code like

```
get('API_HOST_PLACEHOLDER/info')
```

will become something like

```
get('http://192.168.42.23:3000/info')
```