# Images not loading from uri source in React Native project

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, express

I made a custom element, called `FoodItem`, which is to be found in the `FoodItem.js` file and it has the following structure:

```
import React from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  ImageBackground,
  Image,
  Dimensions,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from "react-native";

// any food item has the following properties:
// 1. image
// 2. title
// 3. description
// 4. price
// 5. key

const { width: WIDTH, height: HEIGHT } = Dimensions.get("window");

export default class FoodItem extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.bubbleItem}>
        <Image style={styles.bubbleImage} source={{ uri: this.props.imgSrc }} />
        <Text style={styles.bubbleTitle}>{this.props.title}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.bubbleDescription}>{this.props.description}</Text>
        <View style={styles.bubblePrice}>
          <Text style={styles.priceText}>{this.props.price} RON</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  bubbleItem: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#e3dede",
    margin: 10,
    borderColor: "#bab5b5",
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderRadius: 30,
  },
  bubbleTitle: {
    fontWeight: "bold",
    alignSelf: "center",
    textAlign: "center",
    fontSize: 20,
  },
  bubbleDescription: {
    textAlign: "center",
    padding: 5,
  },
  bubblePrice: {
    position: "absolute",
    backgroundColor: "black",
    margin: 10,
    borderColor: "#bab5b5",
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderRadius: 30,
    left: WIDTH * 0.235,
    top: HEIGHT * 0.14,
  },
  bubbleImage: {
    width: WIDTH * 0.44,
    height: HEIGHT * 0.2,
    borderRadius: 30,
  },
  priceText: {
    color: "white",
    margin: 5,
  },
});
```

The most relevant line for this question, from the above class, is:

```
<Image style={styles.bubbleImage} source={{ uri: this.props.imgSrc }} />
```

I am calling instances of `FoodItem` elements this way:

```
<FoodItem
    key={item.id}
    imgSrc={`http://localhost:3000/getImage/${item.image}`}
    title={item.title}
    description={item.description}
    price={item.price}
/>
```

It is not that relevant where the `item` object came from. All that matters is that the `item` object is, for sure, a valid object, having the following structure:

```
{
    id: 10,
    image: '1.png',
    title: 'Burger',
    description: 'contine vita si sos cu maioneza',
    price: 35
}
```

This is my relevant express backend server side code:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const server = require("http").createServer(app);
const port = 3000;

app.use("/getImage", express.static("uploads"));

server.listen(port, () => console.log("server running on port:" + port));
```

Therefore, the `FoodItem` elements are trying to access links where images are served statically from the `./uploads` folder (for sample: `https://localhost:3000/getImage/1.png`). In fact, I know for sure the images are delivered as they are supposed to be, because, when I access these `uris` from the web browser, they do get delivered. For some reason, the images are not loading inside the `FoodItem` elements, even though they would load images from remote `uris`; for sample, this works just fine (the image is  loading inside the `FoodItem` elements):

```
<FoodItem
    key={item.id}
    imgSrc={
        "https://cdn-media-1.freecodecamp.org/images/1*y6C4nSvy2Woe0m7bWEn4BA.png"
    }
    title={item.title}
    description={item.description}
    price={item.price}
/>
```

Comment: If you using iOS 14 then have a look at https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29279#issuecomment-658244428

Comment: No, I'm using expo for android development

Comment: OK, I think you need to update expo manifest as described here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47417766/calling-locally-hosted-server-from-expo-app